# Laravel URL localization

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to build a website using Laravel 4, and its going to be for multi countries (each country has its own pages/sections) and multi languages probably in the future, so I imagined it to be like this:

```
http://domain.tld/uk-en/section/page
http://domain.tld/ae-en/section/page
http://domain.tld/ae-ar/section/category
```

However I am not feeling that Laravel 4 is helping me to achieve that, I tried to change the url value in `config/app.php` but still when I use `URL::to()` and `HTML::link()` it adds the value after the domain name, not the full url I want.

any help please?

Comment: Check this forum post it might help you [Language slugs in Laravel 4](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9284). You can achieve that by using [route-prefixing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing)